# Android afreechart- how to set panlimits for xyplot

Tags: android

I'm creating a graph using afreechart api for my app.I'm using xyplot with timeseries
     to display  insulin levels for different time and date.The graph is working fine but now
     i want set the limits for range and domain axis that it should not go to the 
     negative  values while scrolling.Can anyone help me,how to set the pan limits 
     for afreechart api?
     I used panRangeAxis(percent,info,source).but its not working for me.

Comment: Good Questions.. I am also looking for this...